# jsPDF, Add text after another dynamic text

Tags: javascript, jspdf

I need to create a PDF with dynamic fields. Sometimes a text can be 2 lines, sometimes 3 lines. How can I do to insert directly after the first dynamic text another element without hardcode a static Y coordinate ?

This is my code :

```
const pdf = new window.jspdf.jsPDF();

pdf.text(`DYNAMIC TEXT THAT CAN HAVE 1 TO X LINES`, 5, 10);

//The next text which must be under the first, but without hardcode Y:20, because sometime, this is too much
pdf.text(`DYNAMIC TEXT THAT CAN HAVE 1 TO X LINES`, 5, 20);
```

I'm using jsPDF 2.3.0 from CDN link

Thank You !

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with jsPDF and i couldn't find any answer.
If you can change the library you're using, i found [this post](https://medium.com/@brahmaputra1996/client-side-pdf-generation-if-you-struggled-with-dynamic-content-positioning-in-jspdf-459aef48dc30) that suggest to try with pdfMake. Maybe it can help you ...

Answer (score 0):

```
  didDrawPage: function (data) {
    doc.text(
     "first title,
      data.settings.margin.left,
      22
    );
    doc.text("Second title", data.settings.margin.top, 50);
  }
```

This tweak worked for me

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same issue, couldn't find any official solution so used other methods for this. Here is my way of solving it. I'm splitting the text to the size I need, then I'm getting its height. Hope it helps

```
  const start = 20;
  let nextY = 60;
  const textOne= `This might change: ${myTextOne}`;
  nextY = addText(doc, textOne, nextY);
  
  const textTwo = `This might change: ${myTextTwo}`;
  nextY = addText(doc, textTwo, nextY);

  function addText(doc, text, nextY) {
  const locationsText = text;
  doc.text(locationsText, start, nextY, { maxWidth: 180 });
  nextY += roundUp(doc.getTextDimensions(doc.splitTextToSize(locationsText, 
  180)).h) + 5;
  return nextY;
  }
```